# Boxplotting X values appearing more than once

Tags: python, pandas, plot, box

So I have this data frame df:

```
 Author | Score
  A     |   10
  B     |   4
  C     |   8
  A     |   9
  B     |   7
  C     |   6
  D     |   4
  E     |   3
```

I want to be able to make a box plot of x = author and y = score where the amount of authors is greater than 1. So the chart will only display authors A, B, and C. The reason why I want to set this limit is because the actual data frame I'm working with contains a rather large number of authors, and the box plot ends up looking extremely cluttered and unable to read. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `transform('size')` to create a mask that limits your DataFrame to Authors with more than 1 row. Then `boxplot` this subset.

```
m = df.groupby('Author')['Score'].transform('size').gt(1)
df.loc[m].boxplot(by='Author', column='Score')
```

[image]

---

That method allows you to easily generalize to an arbitrary number of rows as your threshold. In this special case of more than 1 row you could also  use `duplicated` to slice the original:

```
df[df.duplicated('Author', keep=False)].boxplot(by='Author', column='Score')
```

Comment: Thank you!! Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

First count `Authors` by grouping them then filter data by `Counts`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# add counts column
df['Counts'] = df.groupby(['Author']).transform('count')
# filter by value > 1
df = df[df['Counts'] > 1]

# plot
df.boxplot(by='Author', column=['Score'])
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]